# calling html code from other html code

Tags: html

A good programer believes in code re-useability. I am in new HTML and CSS programming. when i code in HTML i have to write my full code in one HTML file. often many programming logic and code repeats in my code. Is there a way to reuse my code? Does function concept work in HTML?
here i am attaching my code where i have to write following lines repeatedly:

```
<a href="login.html">login</a>|
<a href="logout.html">logout</a>|
<a href="profile.html">profile</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible with pure HTML, but you can use a master-page setup in php or asp

Comment: first understand that html is not a programming language ..it's a markup language . that means it is used just to markup the contents. The code re-usability and other things required for languages like php

Comment: that means there is know way to reuse code in HTML?

Comment: HTML itself does not have "function concept" but you can do that using Javascript. I recommend to you read about javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/ Or you any web programming language - php, pytho/django and so on.

Comment: @vinitsaxena:- What do understand by reusability? I mean in which context are you saying that? Code reusability is generally focussed on functional languages like PHP etc not HTML.  it is better to add html files to the list of SSI file types than to the list of file types that get parsed by something like PHP

Comment: Hey Josemon, i can understand HTML is a markup language. However, problem related to code re-useability can occur while coding. There should be any solution regarding to this.

Comment: @R.T., I have bored to write some line which have been mentioned before. now I feel desire for using those line of my code like function calling in other languages...

Comment: @vinitsaxena:- Thats what I mentioned above, this is not what HTML is used for(And I am sure you are aware of that! :))

Comment: @R.T.: I got the point which you want to convey...Thank you for enlightening me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an overview that I thought about.

Directory Structure:

Root

- includes

  - navigation.php
- about.php

So on `navigation.php` you have the following code.

```
<a href="login.html">login</a>| <a href="logout.html">logout</a>| <a href="profile.html">profile</a>
```

Then on `about.php` by using `include` function on php put it on your about page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <?php include ('includes/navigation.php'); ?>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

There you go.

If you're on PHP, try to Learn Laravel, it's nice. [Laravel Link](http://laravel.com)

**Edit**

I just realized that there's no PHP involved lol.

Answer (score 0):

The best i can think of this:

```
<!--#include virtual="login.html" -->
```

ie, use the [Server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) otherwise I dont think so it is possible. Also to note that HTML  is a markup language, so code reusability is not something where you have to focus upon.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please note that HTML, XML isn't code, it's markup language. :)

Secondly, consider using Template Frameworks in combination with a scripting or programming language. That should promote re-usability of your markups.

ie. PERL with Template Toolkit, PHP with SMARTY, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in css through Class 
   .common{Write propert there which is common}

but not possible in html.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately HTML is not a programming language, so code reusability can't happen in the way that you think it will.  If you however are trying to do a navigation panel or something like that, you can take a look at using iFrames to achieve what you want.

This will help you to include already created HTML files within another.

You can find a tutorial on IFrames [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/_IFRAME.html).

This is if you don't want to make use of a scripting language. You will most probably need one.

Hope this helps!